# Zoom images smoothly with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a picture, which I want to zoom if the users move his mouse over it. Currently, this does not happen smoothly.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Zoom</title>
<style>
.zoom:hover { zoom: 1.5; }
</style>
</head> 
<body>
<p><img src="images/image.png" class="zoom"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `transition` property. Anyway, `zoom` is non-standard property.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `transform` to smooth the zoom:

```
.zoom {
 transition: transform 1s;
}
```

But you should change to `scale` instead of zoom (thanks @val):

```
.zoom:hover { 
    transform: scale(2); 
}
```

I [created a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vz591k6k/), just for you.

Comment: This will only work is zoom is set as a transform: scale(1.5), not with a zoom(1.5)

Answer (score 2):

Just add this css and see how it looks :)

```
.zoom{  -moz-transform: scale(1); -webkit-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1); transition:0.7s ease all; -webkit-transition:0.7s ease all; -moz-transition:0.7s ease all;}

.zoom:hover{ -moz-transform: scale(1.5); -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); transform: scale(1.5);}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make smooth transitions you must use transition property.

```
   .zoom{
    transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
}

.zoom:hover {
 transform : scale(1.25);
 -moz-transform : scale(1.25);
 -webkit-transform : scale(1.25);
 -o-transform : scale(1.25);
 -ms-transform : scale(1.25);
}
```